# Comparing numpy.str to set that contains a single string

Tags: python, string, numpy, string-comparison

I have the following strings:

`label1: 'Yes'` (numpy string)

`label2: 'Yes'` (a set containing only a single string)

when I try to the comparisons `label1 == label2` I get an error because label2 is a set, not a string.

When I try to the comparison `label1 == label2[0]` I get an error because "sets are not subscriptable".

Can someone help me see what I am missing?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `numpy string`?

Comment: I imported data from a csv file as String values using the numpy genfromtext function. When I call type(data) it says class numpy string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sets** are un-ordered data structures, this means you can get value at any index `i`, this is cause only **ordered** structures could be indexed. In set, the order is different every time so indexing value at a particular element would give different results every time which would be pointless (that's why it isn't allowed)

If you want to me make it work there are a number of ways.

**If you have single value:**

```py
if label1 == list(label2)[0]:
    # Your code
```

or

```py
if label1 == label2.pop():
    # Your code
```

**If You have multiple values:**

```py
if label1 == sorted(list(label2))[INDEX_OF_YOUR_VALUE]:
    # Your code
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're missing is that you chose an inappropriate data type for your functionality.  `set` is an unordered collection; trying to grab a particular element from it is inconsistent with the `set` concept.

You have a couple of sort-of-reasonable choices.

```
if label1 in label2:

if label1 == list(label2)[0]:
```